# rewriting a simple C++ Code snippet into CUDA Code

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I have written the following simple C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    int myNumber = 0;
    int numOfHits = 0;

    cout << "Enter my Number Value" << endl;
    cin >> myNumber;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:numOfHits)

    for(int i = 0; i <= 100000; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 100000; ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k <= 100000; ++k)
            {
                if(i + j + k == myNumber)
                    numOfHits++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of Hits" << numOfHits << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I use OpenMP to parallelize the outermost loop. What I would like to do is to rewrite this small code in CUDA. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You could also calculate `numOfHits` directly, instead of brute forcing it with all those loops...

Comment: You haven't asked a question here. What _exactly_ is it you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can give you a quick tutorial, but I won't necessarily *write* it all for you.

So first of all, you will want to get MS Visual Studio set up with CUDA, which is easy following this guide: http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/05/visual-studio-2010-and-cuda-easier-with-rc2/

Now you will want to read The NVIDIA CUDA Programming Guide (free pdf), documentation, and CUDA by Example (A book I highly recommend for learning CUDA).

But let's say you haven't done that yet, and definitely will later.

This is an extremely arithmetic heavy and data-light computation - actually it can be computed without this brute force method fairly simply, but that isn't the answer you are looking for. I suggest something like this for the kernel:

```
__global__ void kernel(int* myNumber, int* numOfHits){

    //a shared value will be stored on-chip, which is beneficial since this is written to multiple times
    //it is shared by all threads
    __shared__ int s_hits = 0;

    //this identifies the current thread uniquely
    int i = (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x);
    int j = (threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y);
    int k = 0;

    //we increment i and j by an amount equal to the number of threads in one dimension of the block, 16 usually, times the number of blocks in one dimension, which can be quite large (but not 100,000)
    for(; i < 100000; i += blockDim.x*gridDim.x){
        for(; j < 100000; j += blockDim.y*gridDim.y){
                  //Thanks to talonmies for this simplification
               if(0 <= (*myNumber-i-j) && (*myNumber-i-j) < 100000){
                  //you should actually use atomics for this
                 //otherwise, the value may change during the 'read, modify, write' process
                  s_hits++;
               }
        }
    }

    //synchronize threads, so we now s_hits is completely updated
    __syncthreads();

    //again, atomics
    //we make sure only one thread per threadblock actually adds in s_hits
    if(threadIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.y == 0)
        *numOfHits += s_hits;

    return;
}
```

To launch the kernel, you will want something like this:

```
dim3 blocks(some_number, some_number, 1); //some_number should be hand-optimized
dim3 threads(16, 16, 1);
kernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(/*args*/);
```

I know you probably want a quick way to do this, but getting into CUDA isn't really a 'quick' thing. As in, you will need to do some reading and some setup to get it working; past that, the learning curve isn't too high. I haven't told you anything about memory allocation yet, so you will need to do that (although that is simple). If you followed my code, my goal is that you had to read up a bit on shared memory and CUDA, and so you are already kick-started. Good luck!

Disclaimer: I haven't tested my code, and I am not an expert - it could be idiotic.

Comment: The inner loop in the kernel is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I believe it is only unnecessary if you launch enough threads to cover the i and j domains [0, 99999] completely. Otherwise, you will need to 'step' to cover the i's and j's that do not have a thread devoted to them.

Comment: No. With i and j defined, there is only one possible value which satisfies `i + j + k = myNumber`. So it follows that `k = myNumber - i - j`, and therefore you can only get at most one "hit" for all possible values of `k`, and only when  `0 <= myNumber - i - j <= 100000`. So just performing that test is enough to know whether a hit will occur for a given `i` and `j` without doing the inner loop....

Comment: The code is incorrect because `s_hits++` by all threads creates a race condition. But the overall structure probably does answer the general question, given that the original code was flawed anyway, as mentioned in the comments.